# Interrogation about jpa/hibernate subselect fetching

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, subquery

I have an interrogation about a code snippet [(full source code)](http://jpwh.org/examples/jpwh2/jpwh-2e-examples-20151103/examples/src/test/java/org/jpwh/test/fetching/Subselect.java) which is the accompanying code sample of a book about Hibernate/JPA.

Here  is the code listing:

```
public class Subselect extends JPATest {

    @Override
    public void configurePersistenceUnit() throws Exception {
        configurePersistenceUnit("FetchingSubselectPU");
    }

    public FetchTestData storeTestData() throws Exception {
        UserTransaction tx = TM.getUserTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        EntityManager em = JPA.createEntityManager();

        Long[] itemIds = new Long[3];
        Long[] userIds = new Long[3];

        User johndoe = new User("johndoe");
        em.persist(johndoe);
        userIds[0] = johndoe.getId();

        User janeroe = new User("janeroe");
        em.persist(janeroe);
        userIds[1] = janeroe.getId();

        User robertdoe = new User("robertdoe");
        em.persist(robertdoe);
        userIds[2] = robertdoe.getId();

        Item item = new Item("Item One", CalendarUtil.TOMORROW.getTime(), johndoe);
        em.persist(item);
        itemIds[0] = item.getId();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            Bid bid = new Bid(item, robertdoe, new BigDecimal(9 + i));
            item.getBids().add(bid);
            em.persist(bid);
        }

        item = new Item("Item Two", CalendarUtil.TOMORROW.getTime(), johndoe);
        em.persist(item);
        itemIds[1] = item.getId();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
            Bid bid = new Bid(item, janeroe, new BigDecimal(2 + i));
            item.getBids().add(bid);
            em.persist(bid);
        }

        item = new Item("Item Three", CalendarUtil.AFTER_TOMORROW.getTime(), janeroe);
        em.persist(item);
        itemIds[2] = item.getId();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
            Bid bid = new Bid(item, johndoe, new BigDecimal(3 + i));
            item.getBids().add(bid);
            em.persist(bid);
        }

        tx.commit();
        em.close();

        FetchTestData testData = new FetchTestData();
        testData.items = new TestData(itemIds);
        testData.users = new TestData(userIds);
        return testData;
    }

    @Test
    public void fetchCollectionSubselect() throws Exception {
        storeTestData();

        UserTransaction tx = TM.getUserTransaction();
        try {
            tx.begin();
            EntityManager em = JPA.createEntityManager();

            List<Item> items = em.createQuery("select i from Item i").getResultList();
            // select * from ITEM

            for (Item item : items) {
                assertTrue(item.getBids().size() > 0);
                // select * from BID where ITEM_ID in (
                //  select ID from ITEM
                // )
            }

            // The actual test
            em.clear();
            items = em.createQuery("select i from Item i").getResultList();
            // Access should load all collections
            assertTrue(items.iterator().next().getBids().size() > 0);
            em.clear(); // Detach all
            for (Item item : items) {
                assertTrue(item.getBids().size() > 0);
            }

            tx.commit();
            em.close();
        } finally {
            TM.rollback();
        }
    }

}
```

The specific part I don't understand is this one:

```
for (Item item : items) {
    assertTrue(item.getBids().size() > 0);
    // select * from BID where ITEM_ID in (
    //  select ID from ITEM
    // )
}
```

It is meant to demonstrate the use of **prefetching with subselects feature** of hibernate and the SQL query that is going to be executed.

The following comment:  `// select ID from ITEM` indicates that all items IDs are retrieved from DB. Is this what subselect prefetching is meant to work? Why retrieve all `ID`s from the `ITEM` table?

Here is the `Item` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
 @org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch(
 org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode.SUBSELECT
 )
 protected Set<Bid> bids = new HashSet<>();
 // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subselect prefetching means that the original query used to load parents is used as a subquery when loading associated children, so that children in **all loaded parents** are initialized in one go. Your query to load parents is `select i from Item i` (you load all items), hence it is used as a subquery for bids (transformed to projecting only id of items).

If your original query were `select i from Item i where i.someProperty = :something`, the subquery when loading bids would be `select ID from ITEM where SOME_PROPERTY_COLUMN = :something`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dragan. Would the query produce the same results without the subquery (i.e. `select * from BID`)?

Comment: @balteo In your specific example it would, as bids for all items are loaded and there are no bids without items. But in general case subquery is obviously needed.

Comment: What I really don't understand is the use of a subquery without `where` clause... What is the point of subquery without a `where` clause??

Comment: @balteo That's what my answer is about. :) Did you read it? If yes, which part do you not understand, I'll be glad to additionally clarify?

Comment: Yes, I did read the answer; maybe I did not understand the part about *projecting only id of items*... Let me research that and bear with me. :-)

Comment: @balteo If you're wondering why Hibernate added a subquery which could be omitted in your specific case, it is simply because it does not optimize that far and it does not know that there are no bids without items which would then also be unnecessarily loaded without the subquery which limits only bids with items.

Comment: I understand now! Thanks a lot. Your last comment about *limiting to bids with items* makes it clearer.

Comment: Do you think you could edit your answer to include that information please?

Comment: @balteo Sure, I edited the answer by emphasizing in bold that the subquery is used when initializing children in the loaded parents (so filtering by referenced parents is needed in the subquery).